# angular mat table resize error on mat sort

Tags: angular, mat-table

Here in mat table resizeColumn used to resize the columns of table. I am able to resize for two columns Annotation and status because this column has no sorting header but uploadTime and size here resize column is not working, when i remove mat-sort-header it starts working.
i am unable find the problem.how can i resize with mat-sort-header??

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort (matSortChange)="sortChange($event)"  
    class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="annotation">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [resizeColumn]="true">Annotation</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data;let i=index">{{data.annotation}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [resizeColumn]="true">Status</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data;let i=index">{{data.status}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="uploadTime">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [resizeColumn]="true"  mat-sort-header>UploadTime</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data;let i=index">{{data.uploadedTime}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="size">
            <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef [resizeColumn]="true" mat-sort-header>Size</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data;let i=index">{{data.size}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row;columns:displayColumns | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 
          itemsPerPage, currentPage: p,totalItems:size}"></tr>
    </table>
```

ResizeColumn directive

```
import { Directive,OnInit, Renderer2, Input, ElementRef,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';

@Directive({
  selector: '[resizeColumn]'
})
export class ResizecolDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input("resizeColumn") resizable!:boolean;
  private startX!:number;
  private startWidth!:number;
  private column!: HTMLElement;

  private table!: HTMLElement;

  private pressed!: boolean;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { 
    this.column = this.el.nativeElement;
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    if (this.resizable) {
      const row = this.renderer.parentNode(this.column);
      const thead = this.renderer.parentNode(row);
      this.table = this.renderer.parentNode(thead);
      const resizer = this.renderer.createElement("span");
      this.renderer.addClass(resizer, "resize-holder");
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.column, resizer);
      this.renderer.listen(resizer, "mousedown", this.onMouseDown);
      this.renderer.listen(this.table, "mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
      this.renderer.listen("document", "mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
    }
  }
  onMouseDown = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    this.pressed = true;
    this.startX = event.pageX;
    this.startWidth = this.column.offsetWidth;
  };

  onMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    const offset = 30;
    if (this.pressed && event.buttons) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.table, "resizing");
      let width =this.startWidth + (event.pageX - this.startX - offset);
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.column, "width", `${width}px`);
    }
  };

  onMouseUp = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (this.pressed) {
      this.pressed = false;
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.table, "resizing");
    }
  };


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the text of your `<th>` element with a span and applying the mat-sort-header onto that span instead.

`<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [resizeColumn]="true"><span mat-sort-header>UploadTime</span></th>`

found in the comments of this medium post: https://medium.com/@imdebasispanda/resize-table-column-angular-5cb58b67367